# does not recognize native methods

Tags: php, methods, codeigniter-4

my methods getFile and getPost , it does not recognize them on my local server, however on my online server it does, I would like to know why and if anyone has a solution please, im using xampp server with apache and sql

try to add extensions install it on different computers and try different versions, however as it is it works on my online server but on my local server the php inteliphense extension tells me that the methods are not declared

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the basics global variables, call methods, _POST, _GET, _FILE etc...
[$GLOBALS — References all variables available in global scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals)

to quickly check the server you can use this

`print_r($GLOBALS);`